# When does an embedded video download

Tags: html, video, html5-video, quicktime, prettyphoto

I'm in the process of transporting videos from being hosted by Vimeo to being embedded as part of my HTML. They're currently in QuickTime format, and I'm using the jQuery plugin prettyPhoto to display them across browsers. (I'm using an `<a>` tag until the `<video>` tag copes with a uniform compression format.)

What I want to know is when the browser will download the .mov file. Will it be on page load, or only when the anchor is clicked?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge the embedded video gets downloaded as soon as it gets load. 
If in you case the video is loading on the page load it will download at the precise moment else after the click.

Hope this helped.